# android studio error with R.layout

Tags: java, android, android-studio

So recently I updated the plugins for android studio and my previously working app has errors in it, before there was no problem when there was R.layout but now there is. is there an easy fix for this?
The image is a picture of my code with the issues and my directory.

Comment: most of the time it is something preventing the success of the building of resource files. You might want to check if there's any error inside any of your layouts, labels, etc. Also try to perform a project clean.

Answer (score 0):

You can `clean-rebuild`

OR

Step 1: Delete '.AndroidStudio2.2' from "C:\Users\Your_PC_Account\"

Step 2: Start Android studio again.(If Android studio Downloading package don't  stop it.)

Step 3: Create a new project.(Waiting for prepare new project)

Comment: Thanks, I haven't tried the whole delete thing but my only concern would be that I still have the problem, I'm only just learning how to do this stuff and I'm afraid I'll still have the same problem